# FCM registration token - is it possible to find token value in app data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to get a FCM registration token value which is **on my device** - just only to test push notification on my device before publishing it to all users. I know that there is a way to get a token during registration and send it to server, but maybe it's possible to find it in some app data without additional implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Just print token to console and test it using postman.

```
var token = await FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken();
print("token= "+token);
```

Then copy the token from the console and post using this api:

```
URI: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
METHOD: POST
HEADERS: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=YOUR_FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY'
}

BODY: {
  "notification":{
     "body": "TEST MESSAGE",
     "title": "TEST MESSAGE",
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "status": "done"
  },
  "registration_ids": "THE_TOKEN",
},
```

Don't forget to close your app before sending the fcm request.